# MYSQL Select case when query returns NULL for output

Tags: mysql

Running a nested case when query to classify entries in a table based on the parameters below.  When I run the code, the output for `Isosceles` returns `Null`. I'm not sure why. I'm comparing integers a,b, and c, which represent columns for each of those distinct integers for a triangle, for instance.

Any suggestions?

```
select case when a+b > c and b+c > a and c+a > b then 
case 
    when a=b|a=c|b=c then "Isosceles"
    when a=b and a=c and b=c then "Equilateral"
    when a<>b and b<>c and a<>c then "Scalene"
end
else "Not A Triangle"
end 
from triangles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: Instead of single pipe, use double pipe `||` for `OR`.

Second problem: Use `Equilateral` condition before `Isosceles`
 So if your sides are `2`,`2` and `2` then as per your logic, `Isosceles` condition satisfies first. So it will never equate it to `Equilateral`

New Answer: In fact, you don't need 2 case statements. Use this instead

http://rextester.com/PTDI48631

```
select t.*,
case when not (a+b > c and b+c > a and c+a > b)  
        then "Not A Triangle"
     when (a=b and a=c and b=c) 
         then "Equilateral"
     when (a=b or a=c or b=c) 
         then "Isosceles"
     else "Scalene"
end as Triangle_type
from triangle t;
```

Previous Answer:
http://rextester.com/ELLB75736

```
select t.*,
case  when a+b > c and b+c > a and c+a > b 
then
(case 
    when a=b and a=c and b=c then "Equilateral"
    when a=b or a=c or b=c then "Isosceles"
    when a<>b and b<>c and a<>c then "Scalene"
    end
)
else 
"Not A Triangle"
end as Triangle_type
from triangle234 t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when a+b > c and b+c > a and c+a > b then 
case 
    when (a=b & a=c)|(a=b & b=c) | (a=c & b=c) then "Isosceles"
    when a=b and a=c and b=c then "Equilateral"
    when a<>b and b<>c and a<>c then "Scalene"
    Else "Triangle"
end
else "Not A Triangle"
end 
from triangles
```

Just try above code.I think you missed  `else` for  internal `WHEN`.
Hope this will helps.

Comment: This still fails the test case because it just replaces NULL with Triangle for the output. Again, the correct output is Isosceles for this particular test case, so it might be something going one with line 3 or the formatting.

Comment: @Codestudio-CyrusKhajvandi Just put sample data for same.

Comment: @Codestudio-CyrusKhajvandi I had also made change to `Isosceles` logic.
Just try this one.